# CSIDH: Why do we need ideals in the form of $\langle \ell, \pi \pm 1 \rangle$ in order to apply Vélu's formulas when computing the action?

Tags: elliptic-curves, post-quantum-cryptography, isogeny

I am trying to understand the action of the CSIDH protocol.

Let $E_0:y^2=x^3+ax^2+bx$ be a Montgomery elliptic curve over $\mathbb{F}_p$ for some prime $p$. If we take $\mathcal{O}$ as $End_{\mathbb{F}_p}(E_0)$, then $Cl(\mathcal{O})$ acts on $\mathcal{E}\ell\ell(\mathcal{O})$ as follows:

Let $I\in Cl(\mathcal{O})$ an ideal. We define $H_I=\lbrace P\in E_0 \vert \alpha(P)=\mathcal{O} \text{ for all $\alpha \in I$} \rbrace$. The action is defined as below:

$I*E_0=E'$, where $E'$ is the unique curve such that there exists a unique separable isogeny
$$\phi:E_0\longrightarrow E'$$
With $\ker(\phi)=H_I$. In other words, the kernel of $\phi$ is the intersection of all $\ker(\alpha)$ where $\alpha \in I$.

In order to compute the $\phi$ and $E'$, papers on CSIDH make use of Velu's formulas. So far, I have found the following theorem which applies to Montgomery curves:

Let $K$ be a field with char($K$)$\neq$ $2$. Let $a\in K$ such that $a^2\neq 4$ and consider the Montgomery curve $E/K: y^2=x^3+ax^2+x$. Let $G\subset E(\bar{K})$ be a finit subgroup with $(0,0)\not \in G$ and let $\phi$ be a separable isogeny such that $\ker(\phi)=G$. Then, there is a curve $E'/K:y^2=x^3+Ax^2+x$ such that, up to composition with isomorphisms,
\begin{align*}
\phi: E &\longrightarrow E' \\
(x,y) &\mapsto (f(x),c_0yf'(x))
\end{align*}

where
$$f(x)=x{ \prod_{T\in G\setminus \lbrace \mathcal{O}_E \rbrace}^{} \frac{xx_T-1}{x-x_T}}$$
Furthermore, if we let
$$\pi=\prod_{T\in G\setminus \lbrace \mathcal{O}_E \rbrace}^{} x_T, \quad \quad \sigma=\sum_{T\in G\setminus \lbrace \mathcal{O}_E \rbrace}^{} \left( x_T-\frac{1}{x_T} \right)$$

Then, we have $A=\pi(a-3\sigma)$ and $c_o^2=\pi$.

So far so good, we have a way of computing isogenies between Montgomery elliptic curves. What I do not understand is the following. In several papers and slides, they explain that we have to take ideals $I\in \mathcal{O}$ with the form  $\langle \ell, \pi \pm 1 \rangle$, where $\ell$ is a prime. Analizing said ideals, we see the following:
$$H_I=\lbrace P \in E/\mathbb{F}_p \text{ } \vert \text{ } [\ell](P)=\mathcal{O},\pi (P)=P\rbrace$$

Since $\pi(P)=P$, it means that $P\in \mathbb{F}_p$. So it turns out that $H_I$ is just the $\ell$-torsion points defined over $\mathbb{F}_p$. The main claim is that we have to take $I$ in such a way because in doing so, we have a Vélu-friendly computation. This is what I fail to see. Why having rational points makes the Vélu computation easier?

In the theorem stated above, the hypothesis requires us that $G\subset E(\bar{K})$. But taking our ideal as $I=\langle[\ell]\rangle$ instead of $I=\langle [\ell], \pi \pm 1 \rangle$ also gives us a $H_I\subset E(\bar{K})$, which would be $G$ in the theorem notation, and so the theorem holds. Why is it then that having $H_I$ composed of rational points $P\in E(\mathbb{F}_p)$ makes the computation Vélu-friendly?

Answer (score 5):

You are right that Vélu's formulas also *work* for any extension field, but then they require arithmetic *in that field*.
Doing computations in $\mathbb F_p$ is simply much more efficient than in extension fields.

Generally, for a "random" ideal of prime norm $\ell$, you can only expect the corresponding points to be defined over $\mathbb F_{p^k}$ for some $k\in\mathcal O(\ell)$, hence if CSIDH didn't have those rational points, one would have to compute in extension fields of degrees of *a few hundred*.

(In fact, the earlier variants¹ of CSIDH were, among other techniques, using subgroups that are not necessarily rational, because it seems hard to find an *ordinary* curve with many "good" subgroups. The core observation in CSIDH is that switching to supersingular curves makes this trivial, simply by picking the prime $p$ of a special form!)

<sub>¹ Couveignes, Rostovtsev–Stolbunov, De Feo–Kieffer–Smith</sub>